# Strongloop app does not load local datasource

Tags: javascript, json, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to use different environment specific datasource configurations in a Strongloop app. I saw at https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Environment-specific+configuration that the priority of configurations are:

1. **Environment-specific configuration**, based on the value of NODE_ENV;
   for example, server/config.staging.json.
2. **Local configuration file**;
   for example, server/config.local.json.
3. **Default configuration file**;
   for example, server/config.json.

I have declared three datasource conf files:
*datasources.json*:

```
{}
```

*datasources.local.json*:

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "loopback-connector-mongodb",
    "host":"127.0.0.1",
    "port": "27017",
    "database": "woowDev"
  }
}
```

and *datasources.staging.js*:

```
module.exports = {
  db: {
    connector: 'mongodb',
    hostname: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: 'woow'
  }
};
```

Now unless I put the configuration of datasources.local.json in datasources.json it does not work. I keep getting the error: `AssertionError: User is referencing a dataSource that does not exist: "db"`

I tried also to add the local conf to staging conf and defined the variable NODE_ENV, but it would not load neither datasource.staging.js. I defined the NODE_ENV by doing:

```
export NODE_ENV=staging
```

Comment: Hmm... what if you delete the otherwise empty `datasources.json` file?

Comment: tried, does not work, what else can I try?

Comment: Is it possible that your current environment is in fact `staging`? I see that your staging datasource config file *does not* have a `name` property in the definition. It would need this regardless.

Comment: Oh, and the connector should just be `mongodb`, I think.

Comment: No, I tried to add the local conf to staging conf and defined the variable NODE_ENV, but it would not load neither datasource.staging.js

Comment: try to remove "module.exports = " from your datasoruces.staging.json

Comment: Are you sure? it is a javascript file not json

Comment: No, sorry misread the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used [node-debug](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to track down the issue. And it came in this particular source strongloop file:

```
node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/config-loader.js
```

the function:

```
function mergeDataSourceConfig(target, config, fileName) {
  for (var ds in target) {
    var err = applyCustomConfig(target[ds], config[ds]);
    if (err) {
      throw new Error('Cannot apply ' + fileName + ' to `'  + ds + '`: ' + err);
    }
  }
}
```

will not merge configs if `"db"` key is not defined in the master file i.e. `datasources.json`.

So, I just modified the `datasources.json` to:

```
{
  "db": {}
}
```

and it worked!

Maybe it is my fault but the documentation is not clear enough.

Comment: It is not really obvious the way it is written in the documentation, but indeed you can only override parameters, not create them in alternative configs

`You can **override** values that are **set** in config.json in: config.local.js or config.local.json config.env.js or config.env.json, where env is the value of NODE_ENV`

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is exactly the case - I specify a port in `config.local.js` but not in `config.json` and the app starts on the expected port.

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to add all the datasources(memory/redis/mongo/postgres) in datasources.json and then override parameters in datasources.local.js or datasources.staging.js or datasources.production.js

Sample file configuration:

**datasources.json**

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "redisDS": {
    "name": "redisDS",
    "connector": "redis"
  },
  "testPostgress": {
    "port": 5432,
    "name": "localPostgress",
    "user": "akumar",
    "connector": "postgresql"
  }
}
```

**datasources.staging.js**

```
module.exports = {
  db:{
    connector: 'memory'
  },
  redisDS:{
    connector: 'redis'
  },
  testPostgress:{
    database:'stagingPostgress'
  }
};
```

Loopback will override database name in this case similarly you can override other datasource parameters like port and user